# Lightning Experience Keeps on Refreshing after login

Tags: lightning-experience

I am trying to log in into my org. It keeps reloading and showing lightning Snowman.  Anyone has a clue about whats is going on behind the screen.

Error Msg on console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error) inline.js

Comment: try from a different browser / computer. What is the url that you see and how it changes while reloading?

Comment: Have you tried to clean the browser cache?  Like Itai Shmida says, try from another browser or computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because the Home dashboard(FlexiPage) has a component which was breaking, and thus it was breaking LEX. The worst part was this was stopping me even to log in into LEX and remove that component using app builder.

Had to reset the Home Dashboard, Used Ant to download the FlexiPage of Home and remove the component and deploy again. Worked charm.